# Calling the special constructor in custom (de)serialization of a class

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I wanted to (custom) deserialize a byte array to a class object in c# and came across this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675.aspx. Now, how do I call the special constructor MyObject using the SerializationInfo as arguments?

```
MyObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

I have a byte array which I need to copy into a class object.

Comment: To do that, you would use `BinaryFormatter`, but I don't think it will work when you have a byte array in a specific format.

Comment: Ya, BinaryFormatter is not suitable for my byte array

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call that constructor, the BinaryFormatter does that for example. In other words, you should deserialize with the same class/framework that you use to serialize, so it makes no sense to ask about deserialization only. You can see in the MSDN docs that there are two sides to the custom way as well (the GetObjectData method is the other).

Comment: GetObjectData is for serializing the object contents into a byte array right? I want the reverse i.e. deserialization which is why I thought the special constructor was the deal

Comment: Not exactly a byte array, more like a stream, and that could mean several things, but in the end, usually, a stream of bytes. But every serializer has a very specific format, and its data can usually only be deserialized by the same engine. The custom serialization you mention is not entirely custom, it is still tied mainly to the BinaryFormatter, and you can only customize _what_ it serializes, not _how_. However you got your byte array, you need the same engine to deserialize it. If it wasn't the BinaryFormatter plus the GetObjectData method, then it won't deserialize it either.